# NSDate gives wrong year

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate

I am trying to work with NSDate and it is not working for me, I am so confused right now. So the basic thing I want works, but it needs to be the day of today and not from the year 2000.

So what I want is that the Date should be the date of today with the hours that are in my string *bU and eU* and not the date from the year 2000 with the hours of my string.

**Here is a piece of my code:**

```
NSDate *localNotDate;

NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[df setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]];
[df setDateFormat:@"HH:mm"];

NSDate *bU = [df dateFromString:[[[self alarmArray] objectAtIndex:arrayInt] beginUur]]; // This is a 24:00 format string
NSDate *eU = [df dateFromString:[[[self alarmArray] objectAtIndex:arrayInt] eindUur]]; // This is a 24:00 format string

if (intForInsideForLoop == 0) { // Setup NSDate on first loop.
    localNotDate = bU; // This gives the date 2000-01-01 08:24
}

if (intForInsideForLoop < timesOnDay) {
    localNotDate = [localNotDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:(interval * 60)]; // Adds minutes to the date of today.

    NSDateFormatter *dtest = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dtest setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]];
    [dtest setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"];

    NSLog(@"%@", [dtest stringFromDate:localNotDate]); // This gives the date 2000-01-01 08:24. it should be like It's Today thursday so 2014-05-08 08:24
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you can use the first part of http://stackoverflow.com/a/20441330/1187415.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer to my problem with the method Martin has given from the post. This method converts an "Time" string like (18:00) to the date of today at 18:00.

Here it is:

```
- (NSDate *)todaysDateFromString:(NSString *)time
{
    // Split hour/minute into separate strings:
    NSArray *array = [time componentsSeparatedByString:@":"];

    // Get year/month/day from today:
    NSCalendar *cal = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateComponents *comp = [cal components:NSYearCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSDayCalendarUnit fromDate:[NSDate date]];

    // Set hour/minute from the given input:
    [comp setHour:[array[0] integerValue]];
    [comp setMinute:[array[1] integerValue]];

    return [cal dateFromComponents:comp];
}
```